# Implementing a simple lookup array

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement, lookup, associative-array

I often find myself needing a simple PHP lookup array/table where I don't want to bother using a database.

For instance, I might have:

```
1 stands for "Good"
2 stands for "Bad"
3 stands for "Ugly"
```

Two ways it could be implemented are shown below.  Is one more efficient than the other?  Is there any other more intuitive ways to implement this?

```
switch($code)
{
    case 1:
        $result = "Good";
        break;
    case 2:
        $result = "Bad";
        break;
    case 3:
        $result = "Ugly";
        break;
    default:
        $result = NULL;
}

$array = array(
    1 => "Good",
    2 => "Bad",
    3 => "Ugly"
);
$result = $array[$code];
```

Comment: second one require less code

Comment: That's exactly what associative arrays are for.

Comment: Simply use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) ?

Comment: @str no, these are numeric indexes on an array of strings. This is what regular arrays are for. :P

Comment: @Sammitch That is a matter of definition. As the array does not have an index of 0, it is not a "regular" array. PHP does not have "real" arrays, anyway, it is an ordered map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a matter of what are you going to do with your lookup.

- If it's just a lookup of key -> value pairs - array is a way to go
- If you want to perform different actions based on the key - it's actually a good use case for [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - no `case` or `array` that way at all.

So, `case` option is inferior in most cases, as it is less scalable and not able to change in run time.

To simulate the `default` case, use something like

```
$result = in_array($key, $lookup) ? $lookup[$key] : $default;
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it came up when I was researching table lookups. Since the question is about efficiency, I thought I'd add that it's better to do a "hash lookup" using isset($array['key']) on an associative array using strings as keys, and simply setting an arbitrary value of 0 or true or whatever you want. The efficiency of isset() over in_array() grows exponentially with the size of the list.

Comment: mind [this](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=shellsnippets/hello-php-world.git;a=commitdiff;h=0d74414b549eccf9f4653a2e01c92fb72cfe70f8) though, lookup from a PHP array needs over 1500% the time a switch and some range ifs do (it becomes noticeable if you do it five million times in a row for benchmarking…)

Comment: @mirabilos thank you for the comment! I have never measured that specifically, but it might not have been the case 4 years ago when this answer was first provided. I have moved away from PHP since then, so I can neither confirm nor refute what you say. However, if you feel this is an important thing to consider (probably it is) - feel free to edit the question to include the information you have (including benchmarking results and other relevant info)

Comment: I’ve only figured it out shortly before writing that, as I’ve been asked to optimise some code for performance and especially memory consumption. Lookup tables are much better in C, and I think they usually also make sense in PHP, but switches should not be condemned fully, especially in PHP, but I doubt most people’s code is going to be run five million times in a tight loop within a single request, like mine is, so it’s probably not very important to them. I just thought it important and curious enough to note.

Comment: @mirabilos yep, I think it is -thanks! Again, feel free to amend the answer to include your findings (or post a different one - as you see fit).

Answer (score 3):

The second example. The main reason being that it's less code to write in new entries, but it's also more flexible code, and *might* be *marginally* faster. But to implement the `default` case from the break statement the 'lookup' line/function should look like:

```
$result = (isset($array[$code]) ? $array[$code] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

appearently you can do this with a much simpler syntax:

```
$result=[1=>"Good",2=>"Bad",3=>"Ugly"][$code];
```

the array is initialized with the first pair of [] and specific value is access with the second pair

i have no idea since which version of php this works i have recently encountered this construction on a random tutorial, will update the answer if i come across more details

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a lookup array over a switch block with very few exceptions.  Frankly, I have a bias against switch blocks because if they are written with proper coding standards, they bloat the script horribly.  Alternatively, you could fight the bloat generated by all those `case` and `break` expressions, but then you get a horrifically dense script.

No, I strongly urge a lookup array.  It beautifully separates the data assets from the processing.  This results in clean, readable, maintainable code.  Furthermore, as your application evolves/matures, you can easily port your collection of data to a database table if required.

About efficiency, a lookup technique employing `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` (depending on requirements) is very fast because of how php can reference the keys.

Using key-based lookups is going to outperform `in_array()` everytime.

Here is a snippet for context...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9NL6n))

```
$lookup = [
    null,
    "Good",
    "Bad",
    "Ugly"
];

foreach (range(0, 5) as $test) {
    echo $test , ' : ' , ($lookup[$test] ?? $lookup[0]) , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 :         // null
1 : Good
2 : Bad
3 : Ugly
4 :         // null 
5 :         // null
```

You can, of course, write out the keys in the lookup array for improved human readability.

Assuming your php version permits it, I recommend the [null coalescing operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator) for brevity.

---

A modern equivalent of the above snippet can be realized with `match()` if you don't need to leverage the lookup array for any subsequent processes. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/oFFgq)

```
foreach (range(0, 5) as $test) {
    printf(
        "%s %s\n",
        $test,
        match($test) {
            1 => 'Good',
            2 => 'Bad',
            3 => 'Ugly',
            default => null
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Definitely the latter, particularly if you have a lot of data...