# How to make a switch in PHP?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am trying to make a switch in PHP but it is not working. Maybe I did not get what the switch statement is ment for or I am using it completely wrong.

```
    switch ( $currentWeather->weather[0]->description ) {
  case 'clear sky':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/sunshine.svg");
      break;
  case 'few clouds':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/sun-cloud.svg"); 
      break;
  case 'scattered clouds':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/cloud.svg");
      break;
  case 'broken clouds':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/cloud.svg");
      break;
  case 'shower rain':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/rain-cloud.svg");
      break;
  case 'rain':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/rain-cloud.svg"); 
      break;
  case 'thunderstorm':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/thunder-cloud.svg");
      break;
  case 'snow':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/snow-cloud.svg");
      break;
  case 'mist':
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/mist-cloud.svg");
      break;
  default:
      echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/sunshine.svg");
      break;
}
```

It only displays the default. I am getting a JSON file from $currentWeather and then the description  can contain any of the 'case' words.

Comment: _the description can contain_  Contain or equal exactly???

Comment: Looks okay as far as I can tell. I would double check the description.

Comment: You're totally right the JSON response has more descriptions! Was not aware of that. And the switch works perfectly fine now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57164177/2943403  **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.  Write `echo file_get_content('"./assets/icons/' . $svgs[$description] . '.svg');` just one time.  Please improve your Unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `$currentWeather->weather[0]->description` equals when it fails, but a better approach (less lengthy anyway, you're not repeating a lot of code) would be to have a lookup array:

```
$images = ['clear sky' => 'sunshine.svg']; //etc... add the rest of them

if(isset($images[$currentWeather->weather[0]->description])) {
    echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/" . $images[$currentWeather->weather[0]->description]);
} else {
    echo file_get_contents("./assets/icons/we_dont_know.svg");
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa completely agrees with this refactor!!!